# How to add values in an IF statement

Tags: excel

I've got some if statements where the true element is a timed value - there is a column of 5 if statements and of these 3 have been returned with a time.

I would then like to take the values that are now sitting in the column and give myself a grand total but Excel doesn't seem to be letting me do this, is this at all possible.

Here is my IF statement

```
=IF(B3="YES","1:19:12","") 1:19:12
=IF(E3="YES","1:26:14","") 1:26:14
=IF(C3="YES","0:54:24","") 0:54:24
```

So what I would like is there to be an autosum value of approx 3:40:00 (give or take a few minutes for the exact calculation)

Comment: Can you post all your code please - it's hard to figure this out from the `IF` statements alone.

Comment: Sorry I think the code is a bit misleading - basically I have two excel tables, one has a list of 'Yes' and 'No'

They are cross referenced in another table with a if statements so if B3 in table 1 says Yes it will paste a time value, the same with C3 and E3

The values in the IF statements are then as follows: 

1:19:12
1:26:14
0:54:24

These are the true results of the IF statements they now sit in a column in the second table - but it won't let me autosum these 3 values to give a total time due to the formatting. Can anyone assist me with this please?

Comment: I am not clear what outcome you want? Is it: if cells B3, C3, and E3 have a `YES` flag then if they total `3:40:00` then do something?

Comment: No I want to add all the three values that have been generated by the Yes flag to then add together in a total time at the bottom 

So a yes flag has generated 1:19:12 in one instance, 1:26:14 in a second instance and 0:54:24 in a third instance - this is because i have set each if statement to produce a different time so i need to get the total of these times to make a final result

Comment: Not sure I follow exactly what you're trying to do, but if you're trying to sum all 5 of your `IF`s (where 2 of them return `""`), it might just not want to add the time with the text. Try making the false result of your `IF`s be something like `00:00:00`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok I have worked it out - I then took those time values and created a 3rd table with Sum if statements and worked them out as a value in total seconds - this allowed me to get a total time